# dynamically added div not appearing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying dynamically add a div to a page.  This is in Chrome. I've looked at several instructions pages. Seems like this should work, but no joy.  I added style attributes that would make it obviously apparent, just to get started.  The code is executed, per "Inspect", but no element is appearing.  Also the element does not show up in "Inspect/Elements/Find".

```
function CreateDragClone(partType) {
var cloneContainer = document.createElement("div");
cloneContainer.setAttribute("id", "cloneDiv");
//cloneContainer.setAttribute("class", "closeContainer");
cloneContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
cloneContainer.style.position = "absolute";
cloneContainer.style.borderStyle = "solid";
cloneContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
cloneContainer.style.borderWidth = "1px";
cloneContainer.style.top = "200px";
cloneContainer.style.left = "200px";
cloneContainer.style.zIndex = "100000";
document.body.append(cloneContainer);
```

}

Comment: Are you calling your function `CreateDragClone` ? Why does it take an argument `partType` you don't use? Please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: use appendChild instead of append

Comment: Along with using `appendChild`, you don't set a width and height on your element so it won't take up any space except for the border

Comment: He has a class on it, though, "closeContainer"... Maybe the height/width attributes are there, even though oddly enough all attributes are being set inline.

Comment: Thanks for the minimal example tip. I'm going to use (parttype) later.

Comment: Got it to work.  It needed the height and width.  I had commented out the class, which did have height and width, because it did not seem to be having an effect.   Added it back, took out the attributes, div did not appear.  Added h w attributes back in, div appears.  append vs appendChild did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify height and width to the created element.

One more thing, `partType` is passed as an argument but not being used, so you can remove it.

```js
function CreateDragClone() {
var cloneContainer = document.createElement("div");
cloneContainer.setAttribute("id", "cloneDiv");
//cloneContainer.setAttribute("class", "closeContainer");
cloneContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
cloneContainer.style.position = "absolute";
cloneContainer.style.borderStyle = "solid";
cloneContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
cloneContainer.style.borderWidth = "1px";
cloneContainer.style.top = "200px";
cloneContainer.style.left = "200px";
cloneContainer.style.zIndex = "100000";
cloneContainer.style.width = "100px";
cloneContainer.style.height = "100px";
document.body.append(cloneContainer);
}

CreateDragClone();
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you should get a little red dot representing de `borderWidth`;
Your code is almost done, you just forgot to add `width` and `height` to the `div` element, on the other hand, camelCase shouldn't have the first letter in uppercase.

```js
(function createDragClone() {
  const cloneContainer = document.createElement("div");
  cloneContainer.setAttribute("id", "cloneDiv");
  cloneContainer.style.visibility = "visible";
  cloneContainer.style.position = "absolute";
  cloneContainer.style.borderStyle = "solid";
  cloneContainer.style.borderColor = "red";
  cloneContainer.style.borderWidth = "1px";
  cloneContainer.style.top = "200px";
  cloneContainer.style.left = "200px";
  cloneContainer.style.width = "200px";
  cloneContainer.style.height = "200px";
  cloneContainer.style.zIndex = "100000";
  document.body.append(cloneContainer);
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```